# Change [spyder] to [spyder-ide]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Seeing a question tagged [spyder](/questions/tagged/spyder) (15 questions tag) I thought it was a spelling error of tag [spider](/questions/tagged/spider) (213 questions). Checking this I learned that Spyder is an IDE. Despite that Spyder is a name of it's own I would like the tag-name to be [spyder-ide](/questions/tagged/spyder-ide) similar to the [Spyder blog page url](http://spyder-ide.blogspot.se/). Since to me Spyder looks nothing short of a spelling error. Links. [Spyder on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_(software)), [Spyder blog.](http://spyder-ide.blogspot.se/) [Spyder (Spyderlib) official page - on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You just need to hover your mouse over the tag to get a description of it.

I've checked `eclipse-ide`, `emacs-ide`, `textmate-ide` and even `spyder-ide`. There are no questions tagged with any of those tags.

Comment: My intetion was that a 'spyder-ide' tag would be self-describing.

Comment: Functional Qyrus, I think most Emacs users use it as an IDE. With commands for compiling, debugging, running and managing a software project as well as source code control I think it can be best described as an IDE. I don't know much about TextMate, just thought I could include that in my trial as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think renaming that tag is necessary:

- There's no other thing called "spyder", so there's nothing to confuse it with.
- None of the 15 [spyder](/questions/tagged/spyder) questions seem to be misspellings.